# Template Parameters Mutually Exclusive

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template with multiple template parameters.

```
    template<typename Appl, typename StoredData>
    class Box {
    };
```

The values of the parameters are mutually exclusive:
i.e. for every value of Appl, there is only a certain set of types allowed for StoredData.

Ex: Appl is List, StoredData - double, char
Appl is Tree, StoredData - int

Is there a way to enforce this restriction at compile time?
So,

```
     Box<List, double> - compiles
     Box<List, int> - fails
     Box<Tree, int> - compiles
```

Comment: Just take only the `Appl` type and make a custom mapping with partial specialization.

Comment: [Boost.MPL](http://www.boost.org/libs/mpl/) + a static assertion will do nicely.

Comment: Or just make the `StoredData` type an inner typedef of the `Appl` type and do `typedef typename Apply::stored_data_type store_type;`. If you want, I can write up an answer to both options later on.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is:

```
template<typename Appl, typename StoredData>
    class Box {
        static_assert(
            std::is_same<Appl, List>::value && std::is_same<StoredData, double>::value ||
            std::is_same<Appl, Tree>::value && std::is_same<StoredData, int>::value,
            "Bad parameters"
        );
    };
```

Here is a working example http://ideone.com/enECW, try changing some of the types and it will fail to compile.

Comment: Also note that this can be generalized in C++11 to have combinations of `Appl` to lists of valid `StoredData` types so that you can reduce the boiler plate code.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose that would work. But just wondering, if I could partially specialize on App1, would there be a cleaner way way to do this - without having to explicitly spell out all options.

Comment: @excalibur: it depends on what exactly you want to achieve, on a higher level than just "let it work with such and such type". You didn't say what you're trying to do, so I can't help beyond that. Although answering your question, I'm sure this is not the solution to your problem.